# Vertical math next to vertical arrow in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

Let's say I have

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (A) at (0,0){A};
\node (B) at (0,-4){B};
\draw[->] (A)--node[auto]{$v\mapsto w$}(B);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

How to get that `$v\mapsto w$` vertical (the `$v$` and the `$w$` should still be normally oriented but the arrow should point down and the `$v$` be on top of it and the `$w$` below)?

How to do it nicely? I guess I could always put a `tikzpicture` inside that `node[auto]{...}` and in there do all rotations/stacking I want.

Comment: Node contents are handled as single entities (put in a single box). So there is no letter by letter treatment unless you switch to decorations or separate the node contents.

Comment: @percusse As usual, you don't know what you are saying.

Comment: wow, I'm surprised that you didn't say *always*. I made progress

Answer (score 7):

### Simple rotation

The following simple example uses a node with multiple lines (`align=center`) and rotates `\mapsto` with `\rotatebox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (A) at (0,0){A};
    \node (B) at (0,-2){B};
    \draw[->] (A)--node[auto, align=center]{%
      $v$\\
      \rotatebox[origin=c]{-90}{$\mapsto$}\\
      $w$%
    }(B);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

There are two issues with this solution:

- The vertical spacing is quite large.
- The `\mapsto` symbol is moved to the right a little bit, because the
  value for the height of the bounding box for `\mapsto` is too small.

### Sophisticated rotation

The idea of Gonzalo Medina in his [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159314/vertical-math-next-to-vertical-arrow-in-tikz/159316?noredirect=1#comment363844_159316) is to keep the horizontal spacing around the arrow also in the vertical direction. This is implemented using two rotations.

First the symbols `v` and `w` are rotated to correct the relative orientation of the symbols to each other. Then a second rotation rotates the whole expression to the final orientation.

Because of the arrow, the vertical center axis in the final orientation is the horizontal math axis in the horizontal case. Therefore the origin for the first rotation of the single symbols is on the math axis and horizontally in the middle. `origin=c` cannot be used, because the vertical position is not the math axis, but the middle of the symbol.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (A) at (0,0){A};
    \node (B) at (0,-2){B};
    \draw[->]
      (A)--node[auto]{%
        \rotatebox[origin=c]{-90}{$
           \sbox0{$\vcenter{}$}% get the height of the math axis
           \rotatebox[x=.5\width, y=\ht0]{90}{$v$}
           \mapsto
           \rotatebox[x=.5\width, y=\ht0]{90}{$w$}
        $}%
      }(B);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: You were faster than me... lol I gad the same idea.

Comment: Perhaps  `\draw[->] (A)--node[auto, align=center]{\rotatebox[origin=c]{-90}{$\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{$v$}\mapsto \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{$w$}$}}(B);` gives better spacing and alignment of the arrow?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: Thanks, this is much better (with a small correction for the rotation of the symbols *v* and *w*).